# How to apply padding from div class wrapper but not on the header

Tags: html, css

I have this styling to a wrapper div

**css**

```
.wrapper {
   padding-left: 2rem;
   padding-right: 2rem;
   width: 960px;
}
header {
  width: 100%; //that means it inherits the paddings
  background-color: red; 
}
```

but i don't want to apply it to the header

**html**

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    -Link
    -Link
    -Link
  </header>
</div>
```

Is there a better way? I tried first child, and the not pseudo class, it doesn't work. I am trying to spread the header 100% of the wrapper, so that the applied color is going 100% its parent element, in this case wrapper.

edit: fixed demo

Thank you!

Comment: Just apply the bg color on wrapper element.

Comment: But i want the bg color only on header, where my nav is.

Answer (score 0):

### First Method

### Better solution - `Relative` positioning header

Add **relative positioning** to header

```
header {
  background-color: red;
  position:relative;
  left:-2rem;
  right:-2rem;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.wrapper{
   padding-left: 2rem;
   padding-right: 2rem;
   width: 960px;
}
header {
  background-color: red;
  position:relative;
  left:-2rem;
  right:-2rem;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    -Link
    -Link
    -Link
  </header>
  Wrapper
</div>
```

### Second method - Add Negative `margin`

Instead adding adding padding negative you can use **negative margin**

```
header {
  background-color: red;
  margin:0 -2rem;
}
```

**working demo**

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.wrapper{
   padding-left: 2rem;
   padding-right: 2rem;
   width: 960px;
}
header {
  background-color: red;
  margin:0 -2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    -Link
    -Link
    -Link
  </header>
  Wrapper
</div>
```

Comment: are you want like this:)

Comment: So yes... Usually i don't like adding all over my code margins, i use only paddings, because it breaks the code. I added the class of padding everywehre it needs. But there must be a cleaner solution.

Comment: You can choose First method more flexible @Becky Beck?

Comment: Thank you, but it messes up my header.

Answer (score 0):

You can reverse padding by setting negative margins this way:

```
.wrapper {
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    width: 960px;
}
.header {
    margin-left: -2rem;
    margin-right: -2rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    background-color: red; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the header `position: absolute`. Also `header` class doesn't exist.

```
.wrapper {
   padding-left: 2rem;
   padding-right: 2rem;
   width: 960px;
   position: relative;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Not bad. I did add a padding class to every section that needs padding, but wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: It really depends on what problems each solution can cause, there are many ways to approach this.

Comment: Yes, I worked it out by adding classes where it is needed. Just because I needed a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply consider box-shadow to color the outside part:

```css
.wrapper {
  padding:10px 2rem;
  border:2px solid green;
  background:#f2f2f2;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow:
     -2rem 0 0 0 red,
     2rem 0 0 0 red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    -Link -Link -Link
  </header>
</div>
```